# I can't use this Javascript function (in its own file) in my Typescript project. Must be something simple I'm missing

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, module

I have a Javascript function that creates a shape in my UI.  This function sets up the parts of the shape and draws lines between them, and has methods which can be called to change sides, height, width, etc.  (The first code line is "function Shape {"  and then variables are initialized next.)

How can I use this function in my Typescript project?  I want to be able to create the shape when I execute my Angular project, and change height, width, etc., depending on buttons.

I'm getting a message that says it resolves, but it is not a module.

I've already tried import { Shape } from '../Shape.js'; in my main.ts.  And allowJs is set to true in my compiler options.

I think the problem might be because the file Shape.js is all one Javascript function.  Should I change it to an export module, or something else?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to put `module.exports.Shape = Shape` in your js file.

Comment: That worked very well.  Thank you very much, Charles!